# Datatable button click for angular 4

Tags: angular, button, datatable, click

I'm using datatable in angular 4 application. while appending my data to table I am using different buttons for different actions

Below is my code:

```
{
  data: 'iUserId',
  defaultContent: "-",
  "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
       return '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-flat" (click)="deleteUserConfirm('+data+')" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>'
   }
},
```

I have created deleteUserConfirm method to perform some action on delete button click but this button does not call the angular method.
Button works fine If I don't use datatable.
Is there any other way to call angular 4 method from datatable.

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz link?

Comment: i don't think you can add js code from component into the template, insead, try to add that directly into the template (.html)

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML as,

```
'<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-flat" (click)="deleteUserConfirm(data)" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
```